# Android listview sequence wrong

Tags: android, listview

I have listview with multiple items. each row containing image and text in zig zag manner i check position if((position % 2) == 0) then i attach image to left and text to right and in else i set image to right and text to left. it works proper but when i scroll up or scroll down then i getting a problem with sequence. i need listview like this[image]

but when i scroll to listview then i getting like this

[image]

```
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null || view.getTag() == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_hotel_list_left_layout, null);

        // get total display height and width
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;

        // divide total width by 2 and store it into newWidth variable
        int newWidth = width / 2;
        Log.d("Width-NewWidth", "" + width + "-" + newWidth);

        int marginLeftSide = 0, marginRightTopBottomSide = 0;

        // if Utility.deviceTypeFlag == "Tab" then user device is tab then set margins according to tab
        if (Utility.deviceTypeFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("Tab")) {
            float density = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int marginLeft = 15;
            marginLeftSide = (int) (marginLeft * density);
            int marginRightTopBottom = 8;
            marginRightTopBottomSide = (int) (marginRightTopBottom * density);
            newWidth = newWidth - (marginRightTopBottomSide * 3);

        } else {
            // set margins accroding to smartphone.
            float density = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int marginLeft = 10;
            marginLeftSide = (int) (marginLeft * density);
            int marginRightTopBottom = 5;
            marginRightTopBottomSide = (int) (marginRightTopBottom * density);
            newWidth = newWidth - (marginRightTopBottomSide * 3);
        }

        // if Utility.deviceTypeFlag == "Tab" then user device is tab then set margins according to tab
        if (Utility.deviceTypeFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("Tab")) {
            int direction = Integer.parseInt(arrayListHotelDetails.get(position).get("directionFlag"));
            if ((position % 2) == 0) {
                Log.d("position", String.valueOf(position));

                // check position if it is even then set hotel image to left and hotel name to right.
                holder.relativeLayout_Image = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativelayout_hll);
                holder.imageviewHotel = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview_Hotel_Name_ahl);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(newWidth, Utility.relativelayout_Height);
                layoutParams.setMargins(marginLeftSide, marginLeftSide, marginRightTopBottomSide, 0);
                holder.relativeLayout_Image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                holder.relativeLayout_Text = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativelayout2_hll);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(newWidth, Utility.relativelayout_Height);
                layoutParams1.setMargins(marginRightTopBottomSide, marginLeftSide, marginLeftSide, 0);
                layoutParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.relativelayout_hll);
                holder.relativeLayout_Text.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);

                holder.textViewHotelName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_Hotel_Name);
            } else {
                // else set hotel image to right and hotel name textview to left.
                holder.relativeLayout_Image = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativelayout_hll);
                holder.imageviewHotel = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview_Hotel_Name_ahl);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(newWidth, Utility.relativelayout_Height);
                layoutParams.setMargins(marginRightTopBottomSide, marginLeftSide, marginLeftSide, 0);
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.relativelayout2_hll);
                holder.relativeLayout_Image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                holder.relativeLayout_Text = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativelayout2_hll);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(newWidth, Utility.relativelayout_Height);
                layoutParams1.setMargins(marginLeftSide, marginLeftSide, marginRightTopBottomSide, 0);
                holder.relativeLayout_Text.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
                holder.textViewHotelName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_Hotel_Name);
                holder.textViewHotelName.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            }

        } else {
            int direction = Integer.parseInt(arrayListHotelDetails.get(position).get("directionFlag"));
            // set margins according to smartphone
            if ((position % 2) == 0) {
                Log.d("position", String.valueOf(position));
                // check position if it is even then set hotel image to left and hotel name to right.

                holder.relativeLayout_Image = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativelayout_hll);
                holder.imageviewHotel = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview_Hotel_Name_ahl);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(newWidth, Utility.relativelayout_Height);
                layoutParams.setMargins(marginLeftSide, marginRightTopBottomSide, marginRightTopBottomSide, marginRightTopBottomSide);
                holder.relativeLayout_Image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                holder.relativeLayout_Text = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativelayout2_hll);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(newWidth, Utility.relativelayout_Height);
                layoutParams1.setMargins(marginRightTopBottomSide, marginRightTopBottomSide, marginLeftSide, marginRightTopBottomSide);
                layoutParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.relativelayout_hll);
                holder.relativeLayout_Text.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);

                holder.textViewHotelName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_Hotel_Name);
            } else {
                // else set hotel image to right and hotel name textview to left.
                holder.relativeLayout_Image = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativelayout_hll);
                holder.imageviewHotel = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview_Hotel_Name_ahl);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(newWidth, Utility.relativelayout_Height);
                layoutParams.setMargins(marginRightTopBottomSide, marginRightTopBottomSide, marginLeftSide, marginRightTopBottomSide);
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.relativelayout2_hll);
                holder.relativeLayout_Image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                holder.relativeLayout_Text = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativelayout2_hll);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(newWidth, Utility.relativelayout_Height);
                layoutParams1.setMargins(marginLeftSide, marginRightTopBottomSide, marginRightTopBottomSide, marginRightTopBottomSide);
                holder.relativeLayout_Text.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
                holder.textViewHotelName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_Hotel_Name);
                holder.textViewHotelName.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

            }
        }
        view.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    // get hotel name from arraylist set it to textview.
    holder.textViewHotelName.setText(arrayListHotelDetails.get(position).get("hotelName"));
    Log.d("textViewHotelName adapter", arrayListHotelDetails.get(position).get("hotelName"));
    String hotelId = "";
    hotelId = arrayListHotelDetails.get(position).get("hotelId");
    Log.d("hotelId", hotelId);
    // set image using picasso to image view.
    Picasso.with(mContext).load("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/foodappdev/hotel/" + hotelId + ".jpg").placeholder(R.drawable.default_hotel).error(R.drawable.default_hotel).into(holder.imageviewHotel);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Your code is extremely messed up. The posted issue is related to the re-usability of row view. I think you should try using Recycle View. Btw, Why you're setting margins dynamically? You can create left & right layout in .xml and set margins from dimen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this issue by adding this line

```
view = null;
```

below to Viewholder declaration

Answer (score 0):

Hi your image sequence is like this 0 3 4 7 8 11 12 15 16 18 19 21 so using

> if((position % 2) == 0)

wont be enough try the following

> if((position % 3) == 0 || (position % 3) == 1)

this will produce a zig zag manner which you are looking for so when the result of mod is 0 or 1 the image has to be put,,

hope this helps